# Confused with Angular Dependency Injection with lazy module

Tags: angular

I've read about Angular Dependency Injection, but I'm very confused with a very simple example with lazy loaded module.

I have created a new angular application and added a lazy module - UsersModule. Here is the structure of an application:

```
|-- src
|   |-- app
|   |   |-- app.component.css
|   |   |-- app.component.html
|   |   |-- app.component.ts
|   |   |-- app.module.ts
|   |   |-- user.service.ts
|   |   `-- users
|   |       |-- user.service.ts
|   |       |-- users
|   |       |   |-- users.component.css
|   |       |   |-- users.component.html
|   |       |   `-- users.component.ts
|   |       `-- users.module.ts
```

As you can see I have created two UserService's trying to inject every of them and practice DI with lazy module. As I understood correctly, angular uses injector tree to resolve dependencies and I expected the following injector tree:

```
 root
   |
 AppModule
   |
 AppComponent
   |
 UsersModule
   |
 UsersComponent
```

Also I expected that I will get certain `UserService` (in `UsersComponent`) depending which one I will import (`../user.service` or `../../users.component`). But the behavior is very confusing for me. If I provide `UserService` in `AppModule` and declare a dependency in `UsersComponent` everything is fine and working, but if I provide `UserService` in `UsersModule` I get an error (no provider for `UserService`). An error fixed if I declare `UserService` (users/user.service.ts) with `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`. Also I noticed that without `@Injectable()` everything works fine, so why is it needed?

The actual code isn't really necessary. I just created an application, created lazy module UsersModule, created component UsersComponent in lazy module, created UserService in different modules and declare a dependency on it in UsersComponent. Please, can you tell me what I have misunderstood?

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'users', loadChildren: () => import('./users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule) }
    ])
  ],
  // providers: [UserService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [UsersComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', component: UsersComponent }
    ])
  ],
  // providers: [UserService]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

Comment: With a lazy loaded module, you get a separate injector. *...but if I provide UserService in UsersModule I get an error (no provider for UserService)* - Which UserService?

Comment: `@Injectable()` is used if the service itself is dependent on another service. If there is no such external dependency, you can omit it altogether.

Comment: @NicholasK if I declare `providers: [UserService]` in UsersModule rather than AppModule and, of course, import `./user.service` not `../user.service`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the picture is probably as follows:

```
                         (root)
                            |
       ________________AppModule________________________
      |                     |                           |
AppComponent           UsersModule (lazy loaded)     OtherModule (lazy loaded)
                            |
                       UsersService
                            |
                      UsersComponent
```

From the lower level (UsersComponent) you can request upper level injectors (declared in the root), but not vice versa. From OtherModule you can't use injector from UserModule.